# Sitecore Commerce Caching - Why an API?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I need to learn about Caching in Sitecore Commerce and have been reading the documentation here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/caching.html

As a developer used to configuring and optimising Sitecore via the use of config files, I'm a bit puzzled as to why commerce has an API to manage this. Surely, its the kind of thing you sent once and then leave? I see API methods to clear cache. When would you typically call these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it goes back to how Commerce Engine works. Storefront talks to CE through the APIs and also Storefront settings are managed inside XP. Most of these settings are cached by the cache store. For example, the payment options are cached by the cache store inside commerce engine. If there will be a change in the payment options, we might want to clear the cache so the latest options are visible. 
If you look at the commerce option in the ribbon of Content explorer, it gives you you the option to clear commerce cache. Most of the cases, we will be going through Sitecore to CE.